# The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.c#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json-deserialization

I am trying to get the result from my wcf service in json as you can see :

```
public List<InquiryStatus> SearchInquiryStatus(string userid, string datestart, string dateend)
{
    string result = "";
    using (WebClient ClientRequest = new WebClient())
    {
        ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        ClientRequest.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/MonitoringInquiryService.svc/SearchInquiryStatus/" +
                                                userid + "/" 
                                                + datestart + "/" + dateend
                                                );
    }
    var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return javascriptserializer.Deserialize<List<InquiryStatus>>(result);
}
```

But i get this error :

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
Parameter name: input
```

As a note when i call my service url `http://reporting.demo.ir/MonitoringInquiryService.svc/SearchInquiryStatus/null/'20171106'/'20171113'`
in browser i get the result .
I googled my error and i found this :

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

I added this to my UI web config .but i get same error.

Comment: Once try with inlining `MaxJsonLength` setting from code `javascriptserializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;`

Comment: @AkashKC it works.thank you .why ?

Comment: I suspect, you are deserializing your json in controller which do not take value from webservices setting in web.config. Web.config jsonSerialization setting are consumed by only web services.

Comment: @AkashKC i added the maxlength in UI Webconfig not my webservice

Comment: IMHO, your `json string` length in greater than `50000000`. And it is working in case of `int32.MaxValue` because `int32.MaxValue` is equal to `2147483647` . To verify this, try to replace `50000000` with `2147483647` in `web config` and see it works or not.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar :That setting is only for web service project, rather than for UI project.

Comment: @AkashKC please post your answer .

Comment: @EhsanAkbar : Glad, it helped you. I've posted my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your UI project seems to be in ASP.NET MVC framework where `JavaScriptSerializer` `MaxJsonLength` cannot be read from web.config setting as you've specified in the question.

For setting `MaxJsonLength`, you need to specify value in the code in following way :

```
var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
{
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue // specify length as per your business requirement
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in your function.

```
 var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
javascriptserializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```