# Can't pass a large string - 2MB - from AngularJS to .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why am I getting the "**The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property**." error when .NET is trying to parse this large string argument (around 2MB) passed to my controller via a post? The call stack is all within .NET and I haven't changed the default value of the MaxJsonLength property, so I am very curious why this errors! If I understand correctly, the default value is much higher.

This one would make sense if I am trying to parse the argument myself, but I am not, it's all .NET: [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

EDIT: .NET 4.5/MVC 4

Comment: You need to set JavaScriptSerializer MaxJsonLength from code as the setting specified in web.config JsonSerialization is for web service. Here is ['my answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257227/the-length-of-the-string-exceeds-the-value-set-on-the-maxjsonlength-property-c/47258664#47258664)

Comment: related to the above statement, what framework are you using on the backend? WCF? MVC? Web Api?

Comment: swestner - Framework mentioned above; Akash - doesn't apply to this scenario, please see my comment below.